# Discrete Mathematics bit string permutation query

Tags: math, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

A bit string is a string over the alphabet {0, 1}. A palindrome is a string whose reversal is

identical to the string. How many bit strings of length 15 are palindromes that don’t start with

111?

Comment: This is math, not programing.  How many length 15 palindromes are there?

Answer (score 2):

starts with 111 must ends with 111 so there're 9 bits left.

The center bit can be either 0 or 1.  For each case, there are 4 bits to the left which can have 16 possible values, and the right 4 bits must match the left 4 bits.

So all together 2 * 16 = 32.

---

Well, sorry it should be "don't start with 111".  Then it should be 32 * 7 = 224 possible values.

Comment: thanks for the post but can you tell why did you multiply with 7

Comment: @UnearthOS excluding the first three bits, there are 32 possible values.  First three bits have 8 possible values.  One of the 8 value is excluded (111) so multiple by 7